# $_POST returns empty on form submit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post

I have a form:

```
<form action="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your First and Last Name *" />
    <?php echo $firstnameError; ?>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Yoyr Email" />
    <?php echo $emailError; ?>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Your Company Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Your Phone number" />
    <textarea name="project" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Describe the scope of work and the most important features of the project *'"></textarea>
    <?php echo $addressError; ?>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="budget" value="1500" />
    <input type="radio" name="budget" value="2500" />
    <input type="radio" name="budget" value="5000" />
    <input type="radio" name="budget" value="10000" />
    <input type="radio" name="budget" value="100001" />
    <input type="radio" name="budget" value="not sure" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="SUbmit" />
</form>
```

It actions to the same page, but when I do `print_r($_POST);` it does not print anything, i.e. no value in `$_POST`.

What could be the reason(s) for this? I studied a few questions on SO on this but none gave me the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You just forget a `i` in `action` attribute ('action' instead of **acton**)

Comment: @JoDev That was a typo

Comment: Stackoverflow unofficial rule #1, **DON'T TYPE QUESTION. ALWAYS, I REPEAT ALWAYS COPY/PASTE**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your passing the name as a Post value, wordpress DOSNT like this!

change this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your First and Last Name *" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="thename" value="" placeholder="Your First and Last Name *" />
```

changing the **name** to **thename**, Will work guaranteed! ;)

Comment: excellent ;) wordpress does NOT like the name value being passed, always good to use your own naming convention. M

Comment: In my case this was the solution, but I wasn't using "name" i was using "id" as the identifier.

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="POST">
```

You don't need to echo `the_permalink()`.

This works for me:

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your First and Last Name *" /><?php echo $firstnameError; ?><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Yoyr Email"/><?php echo $emailError; ?><br>
  <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Your Company Name"/><input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Your Phone number"/>
  <textarea name="project" rows="4" cols="50"placeholder="Describe the scope of work and the most important features of the project *'"></textarea><?php echo $addressError; ?><br>
  <input type="radio" name="budget" value="1500" /><input type="radio" name="budget" value="2500" /><input type="radio" name="budget" value="5000" /><input type="radio" name="budget" value="10000" /><input type="radio" name="budget" value="100001" /><input type="radio" name="budget" value="not sure" />
  <input type="hidden" name="submit"value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" value="SUbmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: still the same..no result in $_POST

Comment: Change the names of input variables o something unique. It sometimes clashes with WordPress's reserved names

Comment: I dont understand why but its not working for me!! I know its basic but cant get it to work!

Comment: Did you change the `name` attributes?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/is-name-a-reserved-word-in-urls

Comment: I had to write my form exactly as you said. Nothing inside action attribute

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
acton="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"
```

to

```
action="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"
```

Comment: that was a typo...Its actually action in the form

Comment: You don't echo `the_permalink()`

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem in my project and solution is in $_POST, maybe you use lower case in your code, change it to upper case.
change $_post to $_POST !

Answer (score -3):

## SOLUTION:

due to request problems, in wordpress sites instead of

```
<form action="http://example.com/">...
```

You may need to point the .php file.. example:

```
<form action="http://example.com/index.php">...
```

//////p.s. echo is automatically done with `the_permalink()` [same is: `echo get_permalink()`