# Empty $_POST in Wordpress Archive Page

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a custom form in my wordpress theme `archive.php` file but I can't get the post of that form. It's empty.

I have these:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<div class="filtros">
    <h3>Búsqueda de documentos</h3>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="f_name" placeholder="Buscar" value="<?php echo $_POST['f_name']; ?>" />
        <div class="dates">
            <input type="text" id="inicio" class="date" name="f_inicio" placeholder="Fecha de inicio" value="<?=$_POST['f_inicio']?>" /> / 
            <input type="text" id="final" class="date" name="f_final" placeholder="Fecha final"  value="<?=$_POST['f_final']?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Buscar" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Even if I pass the variables throw the URL I cant get that vars with $_GET.

¿Any idea?

Comment: Look at your form `action` attribute. You are posting to "#" not the current page. For example `<form action="archive.php" method="post" />` would post to the form page.

Comment: That isn't the problem. Why the GET isn't working?

Comment: $_POST and $_GET are super global variables. That is all they share in common. A $_GET variable is only available through your address bar. $_GET should only be used for non-secure information. Form submission is generally $_POST. However, in this instance, if you want the form variables in $_GET. Then change your method to "get" and your action attr to wherever you want that information sent. For example, archive.php. You can then access your variables by the name attribute of each input. I.E. $_GET['f_inicio'] and $_GET['f_final']

Answer (score 0):

While it's not advisable from a security point of view, you can change the method on your form from `method="post"` to `method="get"` to have variables posted as $_GET variables instead.

Comment: Nothing. In index both works fine but in post archive doesn't…

Answer (score 0):

Change `action="#"` to `action="<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>"`

Try change `<?=` to `<? echo`

Comment: Not working. I think that Wordpress its clearing the $_POST and $_GET vars. In the index I can send a form with no problem but in post archive it's imposible…

Comment: In Wordpress change all `$_GET` and `$_POST` to `get_query_var` function. Read more on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var about Custom Query Vars.

Comment: Yeah, I check that but nothing… It's really estrange…

Comment: Try check this code directly without Wordpress. Maybe WP wants to add some global defined variable in script begining to get it access.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to point the **action="myfile.php"** to specific file.. See the solutions here:
[$_POST returns empty on form submit in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810948/post-returns-empty-on-form-submit-in-wordpress)